# Create Statistics Summary on Selected Columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to summarize some statics properties from several numeral columns such as continuous quantiles, mean , standard deviation, etc., then wrap them into rows with original column name attached as an additional column. I know about using `AVG`, `STDDEV_PO`, `PERCENTILE_CONT`... to get them from single column, but didn't find article/recipe about doing them on several columns at once. Any ideas?

Example input:

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 4.0 |
| 2 | 2.0 | 4.0 | 8.0 |
| 3 | 3.0 | 6.0 | 12.0 |
| 4 | 4.0 | 8.0 | 16.0 |

Expected output:

| Col Name | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Mean | Std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Col1 | 1.75 | 2.5 | 3.25 | 2.5 | 1.12 |
| Col2 | 3.5 | 5.0 | 6.5 | 5.0 | 2.24 |
| Col3 | 7.0 | 10.0 | 13.0 | 10.0 | 4.47 |

Or 'transposed' version:

| Stats | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | 1.75 | 3.5 | 7.0 |
| Q2 | 2.5 | 5.0 | 10.0 |
| Q3 | 3.25 | 6.5 | 13.0 |
| Mean | 2.5 | 5.0 | 10.0 |
| Std | 1.12 | 2.24 | 4.47 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider below

```
select distinct col, 
  percentile_cont(value, 0.25) over win as q1,
  percentile_cont(value, 0.50) over win as q2,
  percentile_cont(value, 0.75) over win as q3,
  avg(value) over win as avg, 
  stddev_pop(value) over win as std, 
from your_table
unpivot (value for col in (col1, col2, col3))
window win as (partition by col)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

To get the 'transposed' version - use below

```
select * from (
  select * from (
    select distinct col, 
      percentile_cont(value, 0.25) over win as q1,
      percentile_cont(value, 0.50) over win as q2,
      percentile_cont(value, 0.75) over win as q3,
      avg(value) over win as avg, 
      stddev_pop(value) over win as std, 
    from data
    unpivot (value for col in (col1, col2, col3))
    window win as (partition by col)
  ) unpivot (value for stats in (q1, q2, q3, avg, std))
) pivot (any_value(value) for col in ('col1', 'col2', 'col3'))
```

in this case - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Happy to know this type of summaries can be achieved with `UNPIVOT` and `WINDOW` clause.

Comment: Also the screenshot showed that I made so awfully many mistakes in the expected output. They're all fixed! :D

Comment: glad you noticed this :o)