# How to generate an equivalent of pandas.DataFrame.describe in bigquery SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

**In Pandas**, you can get an overview of the table (mean, quantiles, count and count of unique values) for all columns by using the following method: `pandas.DataFrame.describe`.

Here is an example:
[image: Example of pandas.DataFrame.describe]

Is there a way to generate such a table **in BigQuery SQL**, **dynamically**? The tables. I work with have tens if not hundred of columns, I cannot write them one by one.

Comment: As mentioned in this [document](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de), you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to generate Dynamic SQL in BigQuery. Let me know if this doc is helpful or not?

Comment: this is not really what I look for tbh

Comment: Currently there is no equivalent of the `pandas.DataFrame.describe` method to generate tables in BigQuery. If you want the equivalent method to be implemented, you can open a new feature request on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent currently, however you can try a way of workaround here:

```
SELECT
  ev_date, -- aggregated dimensions other than metrics columns
  col, -- metric columns
  APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[OFFSET(25)]  AS q1,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[OFFSET(50)]  AS q2,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[OFFSET(75)]  AS q3,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[OFFSET(90)]  AS quant90,
  APPROX_QUANTILES(value, 100)[OFFSET(95)]  AS quant95,
  AVG(value)                                AS mean,
  STDDEV_POP(value)                         AS std,
  MIN(value)                                AS min,
  MAX(value)                                AS max,
FROM out_remove
UNPIVOT(value FOR col IN (clicks, unq_tp, engage_time)) -- list down metrics column here
GROUP BY 1,2
```

The only difficulty is that you have to input all the measure columns in `UNPIVOT` function as well as list down all dimension columns before the new `col` column.

Hope it would help.

Credit to: [Create Statistics Summary on Selected Columns in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862793/create-statistics-summary-on-selected-columns-in-bigquery)